# jQuery show then re-hide all elements

Tags: jquery

I need to find all `divs` that are set to `style="display:none"` and change them to `style="display:block"`.

I need to do this so I can then check the `width` of the `child elements` and then I can set them back to `style="display:none"`

I know how to do this off of a click or other event on one element but I want to do it to all hidden elements at `page load`.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: How many elements are you looking to check? You may have the easies time if you give all of those divs a class, and that way you can loop through all divs with that particular class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div:hidden').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
      //Do your calculations on the children...
      $(this).hide();
   });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div:hidden').show('5', function() {
      //Do your calculations on the children...
      $(this).hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div:not(:visible)').show();
}
```

find all not-visible divs and show them when document ready event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the document ready event to fire off your event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var set = $("div:hidden");
    set.show(); // shows all hidden divs
}
```